# Error - ''Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length"? of undefined''

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning Javascript and they want me to build a [Rock, paper and scissors game](https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/web-development-101/lessons/rock-paper-scissors?ref=lnav).

Here's the code I have so far:

```
let computerPlay = (array) => {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
  array.length)]
}

const array = (["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"])
console.log(computerPlay(array))

let singleRound = (playerSelection, 
computerSelection) => {

if ( playerSelection == "rock" || playerSelection 
== "Paper" || 
playerSelection == "scissors") {
  computerSelection = computerPlay
} else if (playerSelection == null) {
  "Canceled"
}



}

let playerSelection = prompt("What do you 
select?")
const computerSelection = computerPlay()
```

Thank You

Comment: you're calling `computerPlay()` with no arguments. it needs one.

Comment: Damn I didn't realize that you've already figured it out

Answer (score 2):

**Function Definition:**

`let computerPlay = (array) => { //... }`

**Calling The Funciton:**

Remember `computerPlay` requires an `array` as a parameter when you call it.

`computerPlay(YOUR_ARRAY_HERE);`